# How to use Approximate Bayesian computation to estimate the parameters of a function?

Tags: python, approximate-bayesian-computation

I am new in bayesian analysis and I want to use Approximate Bayesian computation in order to convert an odd giving to me by a bookmaker to a probability that the event occurs. Here is the [Python code](https://gist.github.com/pierretallotte/fdf7edfe0cf8d8a081021cd22ec82272) I created to do it but my model doesn't converge. I guess something is wrong somewhere.

To begin, I have a dataset like this one:

```
  odd   outcome
 1.47         1
 3.21         0
10.22         0
 1.17         1
 1.17         0
 2.12         1
 1.82         0
```

I assume my model is a function with two parameters $a$ and $b$: $proba = f(odd) = b + a/odd$. So, the objective of my ABC is to find the distribution of $a$ and $b$. My prior about these parameters is $a$ and $b$ are independents and $a$ is following a normal distribution with a mean of 1.0 and a standard deviation of 0.1 ($a \sim N(1.0,0.1)$) and b is also following a normal distribution with a mean of 0.0 and a standard deviation of 0.1 ($b \sim N(0.0,0.1)$).

Before building my model with the real dataset, I chose to build one on my own to be sure my model is correct. So, I created my $f$ function with the fixed parameters $a=0.97$ and $b=-0.02$. Then, I generated my dataset: I picked the inverse of a number between 0.01 and 0.99 from an uniform random variable to generate my odd using my $f$ function and I simulated a Bernoulli trial with parameter $p = f(odd)$.

Now, it's time to implement ABC. The idea is to generate $n$ tuples $(a,b)$ from my prior distribution, feed the $f$ function with a subset of $k$ rows from my dataset, perform a Bernoulli trial with $p=f(odd)$ and reject all tuples who have a different result than my dataset.

Here is an example with $n=100000$ and $k=5$:

1. I generate a new dataset of 5 rows following the steps described above:

```
  odd   outcome
 1.47         1
 3.21         0
10.22         0
 1.17         1
 1.17         0
```

2. I generate 100000 tuples $(a,b)$ following my prior distribution:

```
   a      b
0.93   0.09
0.86   0.04
1.21  -0.17
0.90   0.07
0.95  -0.16
```

3. For each tuple, I use the odds from my dataset and the value of my parameters $a$ and $b$ to generate a probability using my $f$ function. Then, I perform a Bernoulli trial to get my outcome. For instance, for the tuple (0.93,0.09), I get:

```
  odd   f(odd) outcome
 1.47     0.72       1
 3.21     0.38       0
10.22     0.18       0
 1.17     0.88       0
 1.17     0.88       1
```

I should add if $f(odd)$ is greater than 1, I force the result to 1. Same way if the result is lower than 0.

4. Because the outcome is different than my dataset, I reject that tuple.
5. I repeat step 3 for all tuples and I get my posterior corresponding to all my tuples I didn't reject.

Because I want to perform these steps $m$ times ($m=1000$ in my code), I have to be able to generate a new list of tuples from my posterior. To do so, I decided to make a kernel-density estimate with a Gaussian kernel to create a new distribution from my posterior.

By this way, I hope the mean of my posterior will converge to $(0.9,-0.02)$ (the value I fixed for $a$ and $b$) but, as I said, it doesn't converge. Here is the evolution of the mean of $a$ and $b$ for each step of my algorithm:
[image: evolution of a and b mean and standard deviation]

The shaded area represents the mean +/- 1.96 standard deviation. We can also see that the standard deviation is not reducing.

Is something wrong with my methodology?

---

Edit: I tried to change my prior to one with an incoherent mean and a huge standard deviation and I got these results:
[image: evolution of a and b mean and standard deviation with incoherent prior]
We can see that a coherent value for $a$ and $b$ is found really quickly but the algorithm still can't converge to a precise value for these parameters. I guess my algorithm is correct but my model (my $f$ function) can't be more precise. What do you think?

Comment: I do not understand what is going on from "Because I want to perform these steps $m$ times..." What is the meaning of this repetition in connection with ABC?

Comment: It is also unclear why you need ABC in this simple setting. Regular MCMC does work there.